# Using NSMutableURLRequest and how to manage response/failure

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I am creating an `iOS` app that consumes web services.
I have a class that makes the connections and stores the response in a variable. It also has a status variable where 1 indicates successful connection.
I have set up an `NStimer` and a function to check when the connection and download is done and if it was successful.

My question is:

Is this a proper way to manage the connection and its outcome?
any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using NSURLConnection  ?

Comment: Best solution - use NSURLConnection and delegate for it. Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering.
I am using NSURLConnection and i already have the class implemented with the delegate assigned.
My question was more if the NSTimer was a good practice to check when the request is done loading? I have a function in my ViewController that the NSTimer executes until the request is done and retrieves the data from the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) is the programming guide from Apple Developer website and it describes how to use NSURLConnection delegate. You can manage the received data in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method. Notice that using these delegate methods will load data asynchronously. If you want to handle data synchronously, please try `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`, but this function should never be call in the main thread.